# Криптование (triple DES) в java

Tags: java, шифрование

Дано:

> Ключ -
> 0B20073E16388ADF921F3B8046AD9B54
>
> Дешифрованный ключ -
> 7C7F8F8A0BC83E46738F1CE598FB522C
>
> Зашифрованный ключ -
> 483538316BA882E3662CB458A3B86011

```
неверный код :D
```

Все это горе выдает мне такой вот зашифрованный ключик:

```
bbeee6f8c7b1524ddf41fba8c9db67f408806d45102f4dc32ae981b58e561cc8b63afceeae154070
```

Что я делаю не так?

**UPD**
я немного модифицировал и вот что вышло:

```
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;

import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESedeKeySpec;

public class Encrypt
{    
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws InvalidKeySpecException {

        try{
            String KEY = "0B20073E16388ADF921F3B8046AD9B54";
            byte[] desKeyData = toByteArray(KEY+KEY.substring(0, 16));

            DESedeKeySpec desKeySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(desKeyData);
            SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
            SecretKey myDesKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(desKeySpec);

            Cipher desCipher;

            // Create the cipher 
            desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/NoPadding");

            // Initialize the cipher for encryption
            desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);

            //sensitive information
            byte[] text = toByteArray("7C7F8F8A0BC83E46738F1CE598FB522C");

            System.out.println("Text [Byte Format] : " + text);
            System.out.println("Text : " + toHexString(text));

            // Encrypt the text
            byte[] textEncrypted = desCipher.doFinal(text);

            System.out.println("Text Encryted : " + toHexString(textEncrypted));

            // Initialize the same cipher for decryption
            desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);

            // Decrypt the text
            byte[] textDecrypted = desCipher.doFinal(textEncrypted);

            System.out.println("Text Decryted : " + toHexString(textDecrypted));

        }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(NoSuchPaddingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(InvalidKeyException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IllegalBlockSizeException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(BadPaddingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static String toHexString(byte[] array) {
        return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(array);
    }

    public static byte[] toByteArray(String s) {
        return DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(s);
    }
}
```

У меня ключ двойной длины, его нужно перевести в ключ тройной длины, поэтому первую составляющую мы копируем в третью:

```
byte[] desKeyData = toByteArray(KEY+KEY.substring(0, 16));
```

ну и еще я взял функции перевода из хексов в байты и обратно из пакета `import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ключ `0B20073E16388ADF921F3B8046AD9B54` надо перевести в бинарную форму не через `String.getBytes()`, а напрямую рассматривая строку как hex представление бинарника. То есть нужна процедурка `hexStringToBytes()`  обратная вашей `bytesToHexString()`

Горе вы наше...

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, все получилось! Код добавил в ***UPD***